# F# match active pattern as expanded tuple

Tags: f#, match, tuples, active-pattern

I get the following error in diff with a red squiggle under Subset.
`Type mismatch. Expecting a Range -> Choice but given a Range * Range -> Choice`

Is there some sort of type annotation I can add to the SubSet match so I don't have to use fst and snd?  If not is there any intention to support this syntax?

```
type Range = {min : int64; max : int64}

let (|Before|After|BeforeOverlap|AfterOverlap|SuperSet|SubSet|) (x, y) = 
    if x.min > y.max then After
    elif x.min >= y.min then
        if x.max <= y.max then SubSet
        else AfterOverlap
    elif x.max < y.min then Before
    elif x.max <= y.max then BeforeOverlap
    else SuperSet

let useOldx x xe ye = ()

let diff (xe:IEnumerator<Range>) (ye:IEnumerator<Range>) =
    match xe.Current, ye.Current with
    | After as tuple -> ()
    | Before as t -> if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx (fst t) xe ye
    | SuperSet as t -> 
        let x, y = t
        if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx x xe ye
    | SubSet as x, y -> if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx x xe ye
    | _ -> ()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this:

```
    | (x,y) & SubSet -> if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx x xe ye
```

or you could do this:

```
open System.Collections.Generic 

type Range = {min : int64; max : int64}

let (|Before|After|BeforeOverlap|AfterOverlap|SuperSet|SubSet|) (x, y) = 
    if x.min > y.max then After
    elif x.min >= y.min then
        if x.max <= y.max then SubSet(x,y)
        else AfterOverlap
    elif x.max < y.min then Before
    elif x.max <= y.max then BeforeOverlap
    else SuperSet

let useOldx x xe ye = ()

let diff (xe:IEnumerator<Range>) (ye:IEnumerator<Range>) =
    match xe.Current, ye.Current with
    | After as tuple -> ()
    | Before as t -> if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx (fst t) xe ye
    | SuperSet as t -> 
        let x, y = t
        if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx x xe ye
    | SubSet(x, y) -> if xe.MoveNext() then useOldx x xe ye
    | _ -> ()
```

Comment: Active pattern is such a simple concept but it really does facilitate breaking a complex problem down into progressively smaller parts and it's readable!